# How do I change the title attribute on collapsible content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have these collapsible panels and I want the title attribute to say when they are open or closed. I am trying to get it to work with the script that I am using now but without any luck.

thx

```
    <div class="container">

    <h1>Information</h1>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-target="#content1">
                <h2 class="panel-title" title="hidden content closed">
                    Milky Way Black Hole Belches
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content1" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    The monster back hole at the center of the Milky Way belched out an exceptionally high number of powerful X-ray flares in August 2014, did the beast chow down on a passing gas cloud, or is this typical for black holes? </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"  data-target="#content2">
                <h2 class="panel-title" title="hidden content Closed"   >
                    Tiny Pluto Moon Kerberos Unveiled
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content2" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Newly received photos captured by NASA's New Horizons spacecraft reveal that Pluto's tiny moon Kerberos is smaller and brighter than researchers had expected. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.panel-heading').click(function(){
            var target = $(this).data("target");
            $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
                $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide')
                $(this).attr('title', 'hidden content closed');
            });
            $(target).collapse('toggle')
            $(this).attr('title', 'hidden content open');
        });             
    });
</script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is currently not working because you are applying the title change to the containing `#accordion` element and not the actual title. Also, you are applying a new listener to that accordion each time.

The best way to accomplish this using Bootstrap is to use the `data-*` attributes and then listen for the changes in order to change the title. The code below does exactly what you want;

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnyyq1wa/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
        var title = $(this).parents('div.panel').find('.panel-title')[0];
        $(title).attr('title','hidden content closed');
    });

    $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
       var title = $(this).parents('div.panel').find('.panel-title')[0];
       $(title).attr('title','hidden content open');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <h1>Information</h1>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-target="#content1" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
                <h2 class="panel-title" title="hidden content closed">
                Milky Way Black Hole Belches
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content1" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                The monster back hole at the center of the Milky Way belched out an exceptionally high number of powerful X-ray flares in August 2014, did the beast chow down on a passing gas cloud, or is this typical for black holes? </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"  data-target="#content2" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
                <h2 class="panel-title" title="hidden content Closed"   >
                Tiny Pluto Moon Kerberos Unveiled
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content2" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                Newly received photos captured by NASA's New Horizons spacecraft reveal that Pluto's tiny moon Kerberos is smaller and brighter than researchers had expected. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Update (with text in title)

If you also want to include the text of the heading in the element title, it is a simple matter of grabbing that text in the listener and appending it on.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3795ha2/)

```
$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
    var title = $(this).parents('div.panel').find('.panel-title')[0];
    var titleText = $(title).text();
    $(title).attr('title',titleText+' hidden content closed');
});

$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
   var title = $(this).parents('div.panel').find('.panel-title')[0];
   var titleText = $(title).text();
   $(title).attr('title',titleText+' hidden content open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could you share how I could use the H2 text and combine it with the "hidden content open". I've been looking examples like something(text) + hidden content open

Comment: Can you clarify that? You want the actual text of the `h2` to be combined with the generated title? So when you open that first section, the title attribute of the `h2` is changed to `Milky Way Black Hole Belches hidden content open` and when it is closed it becomes `Milky Way Black Hole Belches hidden content closed`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need :

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){
            var target = $(this).attr("data-target");
            $(this).find("h2").toggleClass("inactive active");   
            $(this).find("h2").attr("title",$(this).find("h2").hasClass('inactive') ? 'hidden content closed' : 'hidden content opened');   
            $(target).toggle();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzseLj27/3/

Answer (score 0):

This sets the title on panel-heading div instead of the h2 but does what you asked: http://jsfiddle.net/x057wp3L/2/

```
<div class="container">

<h1>Information</h1>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-target="#content1" title="hidden content closed">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                Milky Way Black Hole Belches
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content1" class="collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                The monster back hole at the center of the Milky Way belched out an exceptionally high number of powerful X-ray flares in August 2014, did the beast chow down on a passing gas cloud, or is this typical for black holes? </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"  data-target="#content2" title="hidden content closed">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                Tiny Pluto Moon Kerberos Unveiled
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content2" class="collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Newly received photos captured by NASA's New Horizons spacecraft reveal that Pluto's tiny moon Kerberos is smaller and brighter than researchers had expected. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-heading').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).data("target");
        $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
            // Set the title of all panels to be "closed"
            $('#accordion .panel-heading').each(function () { $(this).attr('title', 'hidden content closed'); });
        });
        $(target).collapse('toggle');
        // Set the title of the clicked panel to be "open"
        $(this).attr('title', 'hidden content open');
    });             
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I looking at this trying to understand it better.